# How to add an hour to date in where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2

I've got a filter to select data. In query there is WHERE clause

```
if ($this->date_begin) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'date_begin', $this->date_begin]);
        }
```

So I sort data from any date (if I select 01-01-2000 18:00:00 it shows data from this datetime).
Now I need to change my timezone by adding an hour (f.e. I input 01-01-2000 18:00:00 but it should show data from 01-01-2000 19:00:00).
I need something as

```
 $this->date_begin+'1 hour'
```

but don't know how to code it.

Comment: Just a side comment. If you are designing own solution and have to deal with multiple timezones I would recommend you to store data in UTC (and convert everything into UTC) or use timezone enabled datatype. Otherwise you will have a pile of headaches later...

Comment: have you had a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/timezones.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `strtotime()` php function:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($this->date_begin . ' +1 hour'))
```

In Yii style

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime(\Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp('2017-12-12 10:00:00 +1 hour'))
```

But as Rafal Ziolkowski said in comment, you should convert and store this date in UTC because of timezone problems.